# Symfony3 Image validation for working

Tags: php, symfony

If I don't validate what I am uploading things work fine but the moment I add validation to the image field I get an error of

```
Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed
```

The only thing at the moment I have inside my `validation.yml` is as following

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        firstName:
            - NotBlank: {message: "user.firstname.not_blank"}
        lastName:
            - NotBlank: { message: "user.lastname.not_blank" }
        profileImage:
            - Image:
```

Inside my Entity

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
    public function setProfileImage(File $profileImage = null)
    {
        $this->profileImage = $profileImage;

        return $this;
    }
```

What am I missing here? This used to work fine in Symfony 2.7